# Setting a binary operator Flat

Tags: syntax, custom-notation

I defined a binary operator in as the first statement in a new *Mathematica* notebook.

```
{x1_, y1_} ⊕ {x2_, y2_} := Module[{}, Print["do anything"];]
```

where the code in the `Module` is somewhat more meaningful. My questions:

1. Why does this not show up in a `` ?Global`* `` query?
2. How can I set the `Attributes` for this operation to be `Flat` so it is associative?
3. Do I need to use the `Notations` Package to do this "properly"?

Answer (score 7):

1. **Why does this not show up in a `` ?Global`* `` query?**

   Because you set a definition to `CirclePlus` which is in the `` System` ``  context
2. **How can I set the `Attributes` for this operation to be `Flat` so it is associative?**

   ```
   SetAttributes[CirclePlus, Flat]
   ```

   But now redefine your function so it can take any number of arguments

   ```
   CirclePlus[stuff___] := Print@{stuff}
   ```
3. **Do I need to use the `Notations` Package to do this "properly"?**

   I don't see why, no